# using an array and case statement to display data

Tags: java, arrays, case

I keep getting the error

> error: cannot find symbol case 1: System.out.println(myCar[0]);

I'm trying to create a menu based application program that will create an array of 5 instances of the super read initial data for 3 sub classes.
I want this to be able to display the different car numbers and the user can input the car number they want. The program should then display the info saved within that car.

I want to output the details I set for each of the 5 instances from this.

```
public class Test
{
    int CarNo;
    static Scanner keyboard=new Scanner (System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Ford myFord = new Ford ("AA1B2DD", "A", 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 43.4, 9, 10.2);
        Ford myFord1 = new Ford ("AA1B2DD", "B", 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 43.4, 9, 10.2);
        BMW myBMW = new BMW ("AA1B2DD", "C", 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 43.4, 5.0, 100);
        BMW myBMW1 = new BMW ("AA1B2DD", "D", 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 43.4, 5.0, 100);
        Merc myMerc = new Marquee ("AA1B2DD", "E", 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 43.4, 5.0, 9, "wood");

        Car[] myCar = new Car [5];
        myCar[0]=myFord;
        myCar[1]=myFord1;
        myCar[2]=myBMW;
        myCar[3]=myBMW1;
        myCar[4]=myMerc;

        displayMenu();
    }

    public static void displayMenu()
    {
        System.out.println("Please select Which type of Car\n\n");

        for (int count =0; count <5; count++)
        {
            System.out.println("Car option number"+ "[" + (count +1) + "]  ");
        }
        System.out.println("\nEnter The Car Number you want");
        int CarNo=keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("\n");
        if (CarNo <1 || CarNo >5)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a vaild Car nummber");
        }
        else
        {
            switch(CarNo)
            {
                case 1: System.out.println(myCar[0]);
                        break;
                case 2: System.out.println(myCar[0]);
                        break;
                case 3: System.out.println(myCar[0]);
                        break;
                case 4: System.out.println(myCar[0]);
                        break;
                case 5: System.out.println(myCar[0]);
                        break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try: `System.out.println(myCar[CarNo]);` in each case...

Answer (score 1):

The `myCar` variable is not visible in `displayMenu()` method. Try passing it in as parameter like:

```
public static void displayMenu(Car[] myCar)
```

Also, @ryekayo's suggestion will give you accurate results.

Also make sure that `Car` class has a `toString()` method in order to print it.

Comment: ive done that and i get the error: error: method displayMenu in class Test cannot be applied to given types;
                displayMenu();
                ^
  required: Car[]
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: post your new code as I cannot make out what you mean in your current code.